# Watir : How to set text in this condition in watir automation?

Tags: watir

I am trying to set text but it doesn't contain id, and class is same as of password.

```
<form> 
   <div class="form-group">
     <input type="email" 
     placeholder="johndoe@example.com" class="login-form-control"> </div> 
   <div class="form-group">
     <input type="password" placeholder="password" class="login-form-
     control">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Please [edit] your question and state clearly what you are getting with the code you posted, what does not work and what you want to archieve. See our [guide on how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a good question.

Comment: Haha it's crystal clear.

Comment: The question can stand to have more details about what was tried and what didn't work, but the question itself isn't unclear if you understand what Watir is/does.

Comment: Ok, then I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: Actually @akraf you are correct.. there are two input fields, he does not state which one he is trying to set, he hasn't included any sample code in the question, so we have no idea what has been tried.   a lot has to be assumed in order to answer.  the question could be far better

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden thanks i had corrected. can you suggest me how to to question in this scenario.

Comment: well did you read the 'guide on how to ask' link in the first comment?  thats a good starting point.    Mostly it's be clear in exactly what you are asking, and provide samples of code you have already tried to use to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the difference in the type attribute to locate the fields:

```
browser.text_field(type: 'email').set('user')
browser.text_field(type: 'password').set('password')
```

If there are other email/password fields on the page, you might need to be more specific - eg combine with the class attribute:

```
browser.text_field(type: 'email', class: 'login-form-control').set('user')
browser.text_field(type: 'password', class: 'login-form-control').set('password')
```

Another option would be to use the placeholder attribute:

```
browser.text_field(placeholder: 'johndoe@example.com').set('user')
browser.text_field(placeholder: 'password').set('password')
```

Comment: Sure in signup page this case won't work retype password will be there.

Comment: It would help if you provide the HTML for the other scenario.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `index: 1` to differentiate retype from initial password entry field.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the DOM placeholder for the selection

```
browser.text_field(placeholder: 'johndoe@example.com').set('user')
browser.text_field(placeholder: 'password').set('password')
browser.text_field(placeholder: 'confirm password').set('password')
```